# What exactly is Java's new helper tool? Updating from Java 8 update 60 to Java update 71 on a Mac

Tags: mac, java, malware, adware

I've looked around online and can't seem to find that much information of what Java's new helper tool is. I've found another [thread here on SE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35003620/java-8-update-71-is-trying-to-install-a-new-helper-tool-on-mac)  but it doesn't explain that much. Is it something that offers bloatware and tries to get you to download them?

I was updating Java and it prompted me to sign in with my admin account to install Java's new helper tool. Did anyone else encounter this issue? If so, did you find a way to uninstall it or did you keep it on your machine.

[image]

Comment: You are reading to much into the actual text of the prompt.  Its not actually "new", its just a helper tool, there can be multiple helper tools.  The tool that wants to be installed would be "new" to your configuration.  The solution is identical to the link thread, you can disable the tool from being even installed, how you do that has already been provided.

Comment: @Ramhound. If I'm reading the solution correctly: Since I agreed to Install Helper, it means that I installed "various products" from other companies?

Comment: If you put in your username and password, then yes, various products would be installed.

Comment: @Ramhound. I'm reading the documentation at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/mac_jre.html in the section labeled "Installing JRE 8u40". I'm still a little bit confused. Is the helper tool different from various products? The documentation makes it seem like the installation asks to download various products after asking to install the new helper tool.

Comment: As I said.  The actual prompt is deceptive.  Its not actually "new" its just additional software, unless you have not installed the other software I suppose, its a poorly worded prompt.  If you don't want the software, just don't install it, its optional.

Comment: @Ramhound. Just to confirm: The helper tool just additional software. I still don't know what the behavior of helper tool is. Is this the "various software" that Oracle mentions in the documentation? I wasn't prompted for any toolbars or products to be installed while I was updating Java except for this helper tool. I might just nuke my machine just in case.

Comment: Nothing has been installed unless you provided your username and password at that prompt

Comment: I unfortunately signed in to install the Helper tool. Am I the only one that is confused by this? The documentation is a bit vague and it's concerning.

Comment: @Ramhound The "helper tool" is not new. It is the the installer application that actually install Java. See my answer

Comment: @DavidPostill - I know that David.  Hence the reason I said the prompt is poorly worded.  What I didn't realize is that it was the Java installer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### What exactly is Java's new helper tool?

The **helper tool** is an application used to install Java.

> For the past couple of releases, Oracle has used a standard installer package to install Java 8. With the release of Java 8 Update 65 though, **Oracle returned to using an application to install Java**.
>
> Oracle’s Java 8 Update 65 install application has the following behavior:
>
> This application will prompt for admin privileges before fully
> launching.
>
> [image: ![enter image description here]
>
> Once you provide admin authentication, the application launches.
>
> [image: ![![enter image description here]

Source [Oracles Java 8 Update 65 – The return of the Java install application](https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2015/10/20/oracles-java-8-update-65-the-return-of-the-java-install-application/)

---

Answer (score -2):

The "helper tool" seems to be a menu asking if I'd like to use Yahoo as my browser, which I do not regard as help.

Comment: Your "helper tool" is not the one referred to in the question. You have download a version of Java "bundled" with adware/sponsored software.